# need some direction with mongodb to calculate and sum all records to find a percentage

Tags: mongodb

i got mongodb with fields as : callDirection , status , duration , billsec
what im trying to find is all calls that was answered in less then 60 seconds.
the calculation is duration minus billsec , so if duration is 100 and billsec is 35 then
the call was answered after 65 seconds and that i dont want to calculate .

what i need is to search for all calls that was answered in less then 60 seconds and calculate the precentage from the total of all answered calls together with those that was answered after 60 seconds .
what i got all ready is just the amount of the answered calls from there im stuck

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: 0,
      answer: {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "ANSWERED",
                "$status"
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      answer: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/9ZBHNblktsN

thanks for any help an direction

Comment: Do you have any **specific**question about this? Why is this question tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as far as your code that you wrote here, you don't need to make it that complicated to return the answered calls. You can just use the [$match](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) aggregation where you would just match all fields that have status equal to "ANSWERED".

Then, to calculate all the calls that were answered in less than 60 seconds, and to count all of the answered calls, you need to examine the $group aggregate function.

So, to calculate calls that were answered in less than 60 seconds you can use something like this:

```
answeredLessThan60: {
    $sum: {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          $lt: [
            {
              $subtract: [
                "$duration",
                "$billsec"
              ]
            },
            60
          ]
        },
        then: 1,
        else: 0
      }
    }
  },
```

**Note: This was done assuming that the duration and billsec fields are integers instead of strings as it was shown in the Mongo playground link, if you must have strings here than this would not work correctly**

Here, you are basically doing a sum of all fields that have the result of `duration - billsec` operation less than 60, and ignore all the fields that don't meet that criteria

To calculate all the answered calls, since you already matched all answered calls, you just need to sum all of the objects you have returned

Finally, to print out all the needed fields and calculate the percentage, using $project you can use something like this(obviously if you want to change the field names, feel free to do so):

```
$project: {
  _id: 0,
  answeredLessThan60: 1,
  totalAnswered: 1,
  percentage: {
    $multiply: [
      {
        $divide: [
          "$answeredLessThan60",
          "$totalAnswered"
        ]
      },
      100
    ]
  }
}
```

Here, we just divide the calls that are answered in less than 60 seconds with the number of answered calls and then multiply it to get a percentage

Final query would be this (if you want to try and solve it on your own, obviously skip this part):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
$match: {
  status: "ANSWERED"
}},
{
$group: {
  _id: null,
  answeredLessThan60: {
    $sum: {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          $lt: [
            {
              $subtract: [
                "$duration",
                "$billsec"
              ]
            },
            60
          ]
        },
        then: 1,
        else: 0
      }
    }
  },
  totalAnswered: {
    $sum: 1
  }
}},
{
$project: {
  _id: 0,
  answeredLessThan60: 1,
  totalAnswered: 1,
  percentage: {
    $multiply: [
      {
        $divide: [
          "$answeredLessThan60",
          "$totalAnswered"
        ]
      },
      100
    ]
  }
}
}])
```

Comment: thanks for the long wow :),explanation , im geting an error can't $subtract string from string : https://mongoplayground.net/p/mV__dFl9m1n

Comment: Yes, as I said in the note part, this was assuming that `billsec` and `duration` are integers, so for your data on the left instead of 

`"duration": "100",
   "billsec": "50"`

you would use
`"duration": 100,
 "billsec": 50`

for all fields, [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uHEUM1lSHLb)

Comment: YES, thats was it :) , thanks a lot for perfect answer , i learned something new today ;)